# Vectorise numpy code on demand

Tags: numpy

Suppose I have a very basic function in Python:

```
def f(x, y):
   return x + y
```

Then I can call this with scalars, `f(1, 5.4) == 6.4` or with numpy vectors of arbitrary (but the same) shape.  E.g. this works:

```
x = np.arange(3)
y = np.array([1,4,2.3])
f(x, y)
```

which gives an array with entries 1, 5, 4.3.

But what if f is more complicated?  For example, `xx` and `yy` are 1D numpy arrays here.

```
def g(x, y):
   return np.sum((xx - x)**2 + (yy - y)**2)
```

(I hasten to add that I'm not interested in this *specific* `g`, but in general strategies...)  Then `g(5, 6)` works fine, but if I want to pass numpy arrays, I seem to have to write a very different function with explict broadcasting etc.  For example:

```
def gg(x, y):
   xfull = np.stack([x]*len(xx),axis=-1)
   yfull = np.stack([y]*len(xx),axis=-1)
   return np.sum((xfull - xx)**2 + (yfull - yy)**2, axis=-1)
```

This does now work with scalars and arrays.  But it seems like a mess, and is hard to read.

> Is there a better way?

Comment: Is `gg` the actual function that you would to use on your data or are you looking for a way to operate any generic function/set of operations on your data? Also, your `gg` doesn't seem to work on 1D inputs.

Comment: As I said: "I'm not interested in this specific `g`".  So, yes to "...operate any generic function/set of operations on your data?"  Or maybe just a canonical way to write a function (so, given some `g` maybe I have to manually write `gg`, but it shouldn't be the case that writing `gg` is terribly hard...)

I think the `gg` example does work fine on 1D inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
def g(x, y):
    return np.sum((xx - x)**2 + (yy - y)**2)
```

my first questions are:

- this is written with scalar `x` and `y` in mind?
- what are `xx` and `yy`?  You say 1d arrays. Same length?
- why aren't they parameters?  Because in this context they are fixed?
- in words, this offsets `xx` and `yy` by constant amounts and takes the sum of their squares, returning a single value?

My next step is to explore the 'broadcasting' limits of this expression. For example it runs for any `x` that can be used in `xx-x`.  That could be a 0d array, a one element 1d array, an array with the same shape as `xx`, or anything else that can 'broadcast' with `xx.  That's where a thorough understanding of 'broadcasting' is essential.

```
g(1,2)
g(xx,xx)
g(xx[:,None],yy[None,:])
```

`xx-xx[:,None]` though produces a 2d array. `np.sum` as written takes the sum over all values, i.e. a flattened.  Your `gg` suggests you want to sum on the last axis.  If so go ahead and put that in `g`

```
def g(x, y):
    return np.sum((xx - x)**2 + (yy - y)**2, axis=-1)
```

Your use of `stack` in `gg` produces:

```
In [101]: xx
Out[101]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
In [103]: np.stack([np.arange(3)]*len(xx), axis=-1)
Out[103]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

I would have written that as `x[:,None]`

```
In [104]: xx-_
Out[104]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [-1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-2, -1,  0,  1,  2]])
In [105]: xx-np.arange(3)[:,None]
Out[105]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [-1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-2, -1,  0,  1,  2]])
```

That does not work with scalar `x`; but this does

```
xx-np.asarray(x)[...,None]
```

`np.array` or `np.asarray` is commonly used as the start of `numpy` functions to accommodate scalar or list inputs.  `...` is handy when dealing with a variable number of dimensions.  `reshape(...,-1)` and `[...,None]` are widely used to expand or generalize dimensions.

I've learned a lot by looking the Python code of `numpy` functions.  I've also learned from years of work with MATLAB to be pedantic about dimensions.  Keep track of intended and actual array shapes.  It helps to use test shapes that will highlight errors. Test with a (2,3) array instead of an ambiguous (3,3) one.

Comment: Nice answer; thank you.  I think I've learnt to read the docs more closely-- the `...` and `np.newaxis` (aka `None`) indexes are very handy.  And the broadcast rule that dimensions of size 1 and not stepped along makes it all hang together.  Link: [Broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#broadcasting)